# Switch between subforms in Navigation Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been searching for hours on what seems like an easy question, so alas, I will ask here.  Working in MS Access with a navigation form, attempting to switch between navigation buttons/tabs in VBA to search for assets I wish to add to the project.

I have a Navigation Form with a number of navigation buttons to include btnUpdateProject and (hidden) btnSearch.  btnUpdateProject has a subform named ProjectIndex with a btnSearchForAsset button (so I can search for assets I may wish to add to the project).  I have VBA code:

```
Private Sub btnSearchForAsset_Click()
    Me.Parent!btnSearch.Visible = True
    Me.Parent!btnSearch.SetFocus
End Sub
```

The btnSearch becomes visible, per first command; however, the focus remains on btnUpdateProject.  How do I get the btnSearchForAsset to be the focus?  Much thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you clarify what you are doing? You would search database tables for assets, not subforms.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to navigate to the form page and than setfocus on button.

```
Me.TabCtl1.Pages(1).SetFocus ; This will set focus on the Navigation page 
Me.Parent!btnSearch.Visible = True
Me.Parent!btnSearch.SetFocus
```

Comment: I'm using navigational controls, not tab controls so this doesn't work for me.